# Entidades raíz confiables

Tags: ssl, certificado-ssl

Mi pregunta es acerca de los certificados TLS de los navegadores. Sé que existe una lista de entidades raíz confiables por defecto en los navegadores, pero ¿La lista es la misma para todos los navegadores y donde puedo encontrar esa lista?.

Si miro en la configuración de Chrome podría encontrar la lista pero ¿puedo encontrarla también en alguna página oficial para contrastar la información?.Saludos

Comment: La lista de Chrome es la que tenga el sistema operativo (la misma que Windows Explorer en Windows), pero algunos navegadores (como Firefox) tienen su propio listado de entidades certificadoras de confianza. No existe "página oficial" de esa lista, si no que cada navegador o sistema operativo tiene confianza con ciertas CA y ésta puede perderse si infringen las normas que imponen ([ver este ejemplo](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2016/10/24/distrusting-new-wosign-and-startcom-certificates/)) y ese navegador o sistema operativo puede dejar de confiar, pero otros pueden seguir confiando en él.

Comment: Cada navegador y/o sistema operativo distribuye las actualizaciones en las entidades certificadoras de confianza con los parches de seguridad o actualizaciones del programa.